# Solr PatternReplaceFilterFactory process unmatching values

Tags: regex, solr, indexing

I have a field which is used to categorize documents by a certain part of their name. Most of the documents have a name which follows a pattern like two chars followed by two decimals and so on... What I want to extract is the first 2 chars which is working with the following definition.

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="^.*(\D{2})\d{2}.*$" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>
```

The problem here is that unmatching entries get indexed by their exact name but I want them to stand under "uncategorized" and I need a way to replace that with something like that. How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [length filter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LengthFilterFactory) after the pattern replace filter, provided the docs that do not match your pattern will always have a field length of 3 or more:

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="^.*(\D{2})\d{2}.*$" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="2" />
```

This will make the field empty for all docs that do not match your pattern.

However if you want the field value to be 'uncategorized' for such cases, then follow the length filter with another PatternReplaceFilterFactory, which replaces empty tokens with 'uncategorized':

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                    pattern="^$" replacement="uncategorized"/>
```

**Alternatively**: you can replace all tokens whose length is 3 or more with 'uncategorized' directly like this:

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                    pattern="^.*(\D{2})\d{2}.*$" replacement="$1" replace="all"/>
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                    pattern="^.{3,}$" replacement="uncategorized" replace="all"/>
```

Comment: though this seems to work its not 100% failsafe but should be ok for now :) thanks